# Android, Augmented Reality: Adding a flower image with Picture frame on camera

Tags: android, opencv, augmented-reality

I am new.

I've been playing around with Augmented Reality for awhile and would like some help in doing something simple.  I searched around and weren't able to get a complete picture-answer on what I need.

I have a picture of a flower that I want "augment" to a photo or camera taking photo.

I want to provide a frame on the picture.

So thats what I want to do.  Is there a suggestion or tutorial in doing this using OpenCV or anything that can get it done quickly?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Surely, OpenCV has tutorials like this. With OpenCV you can intercept a frame from Camera, modify it and display it then. Of course, they don't have the flower thing but check a similar sample where they are applying effects it's called image-manipulation http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/O4A_SDK.html#import-opencv-library-and-samples-to-the-eclipse